# How Do I Target A Specific Node In React Component and Have Independent Behavior When Component is Reused?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to target a specific node in my react reusable component and perform an operation on it. But I want to be able to do same thing several times independently because I will be returning this my reusable component several times on the same page on my App.js. How do I target that div node uniquely?

Here is my situation:

I created a react class component (I am not using function component for this project). This component contains two divs and a button. The first div is a red box. Under it is the second div which is empty with the class "result". There is also a button. When I click this button, the package **Html2Canvas** will convert the first div into an image and append it to the second div.

Now from the Html2Canvas documentation, they only specified how to append the generated canvas to the body of the DOM:

```
   html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
```

Since I needed to append to that empty second div, I did:

```
 html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
        document.queryselector('.result').appendChild(canvas)
    });
```

This would have been fine if I am just using this component once on a page, but in my App.js, I am actually returning this my component multiple times, so what now happens is that each time I click that button, it targets only the first instance of the empty whereas what I need is that each occurrence of my component should behave like the first one independently.

Yes I have tried using CreateRef() to target the current occurrence oof the empty dive but it does not work. It sees the ref as undefined when I call it inside the Html2Caanvas function. But outside of it, it is defined. Ok I tried creating the ref inside, still gave an error of undefined.

I understand that this whole thing I have written may be somewhat vague, so here is a [CodeSandBox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/tgwd2g) of what I want.

When you open it and click on the first "Finish" button, you will see that the red box gets converted to an image, and the image is added under the red box, that is, it is appended to the div with class "result". But when you click on the second "Finish" button, instead of the generated image of the blue box coming under the blue box div, it goes under or beside the previous image. The expected behavior is for it to appear under the blue box. And if I replicate that component "ReUsable" as many times as I want in the App.js, the same behavior is expected. Independence.

I know this is a lot. I look forward to and appreciate your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

First, the ref approach was great (the one you commented out), only that you were referencing the containerRef and not the screenshotRef.

the main issue came from the callback function passed to html2canvas, even though you called bind on handleFinish, binding "this" context to the current class context, the execution context of "this" in the callback is undefined because you used a regular function and regular function always refers to the context of the function being called(html2canvas).

arrow functions on the other hand treat the "this" keyword differently. They don't define their own context.

kindly update your handleFinish method to this

```
handleFinish(event) {
    html2canvas(this.containerRef.current, 1).then((canvas) =>{
      this.screenshotRef.current.append(canvas); 
     // document.querySelector(".result").append(canvas);
    });
  }
```

Comment: hey @anatugreen did the solution work out for you

Comment: Hi @coder4Christ, So sorry that I have not responded since. I will revert this week. I have been swamped lately. Thanks for understanding